# Picture and source image to show images AWS S3

Tags: html, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem in the html to make the images from aws s3 work using CloudFront on the website, I want to use the picture source to change the image responsively according to the screen size.

I tested using nextjs and pure html and neither worked.

My Code:

```
<picture>

<source srcset="https://files.agenciaarara.com.br/files/banners/Consorcio Volvo8ff9792c-b45e-4caa-9c16-2f7b2e293dcf-Consorcio Volvo7ee23acc-b333-4616-9528-2db88ea0bfca-fiat_banner-site_varejo_fastback-toro_desktop.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)">

<img src="https://files.agenciaarara.com.br/files/banners/Consorcio Volvo246d65aa-de68-4553-abf4-74fd9cd65db3-download.png" alt="teste" class="w-100">

</picture>
```

That said, it does not display the source image at any time.

I tried several ways to make it work, and I wouldn't want to use UseEffect to perform such an action.

Comment: The images are getting returned with a `Content-Type:
application/octet-stream` response header, which is likely to blame. (Whether you'd have to fix that on the s3 or the cloudfront side of things, I couldn't tell you though.)

Comment: I changed it to the correct mime type of the image and it still doesn't work

<picture><source srcset="https://files.agenciaarara.com.br/files/banners/Consorcio Volvo2f20c4cf-5b39-4a9a-9835-d422c63bbf30-xc90-phev-my24-responsive.jpg" media="(min -width: 768px)"><img src="https://files.agenciaarara.com.br/files/banners/Consorcio Volvo5c58a835-e1df-4d5f-a9eb-bcfca90b3338-ex30-bev-my24-responsive-reveal.webp " alt="test 2" class="w-100"></picture>

Comment: That works fine for me here, https://jsfiddle.net/L6vph5en/

Comment: the black car is not shown, only the white one

Comment: Both URLs _work_ fine. That the `picture` element is not _showing_ both of them at the same time - that is the _intended_ functionality.

Comment: I do not know what to do

Comment: Both these image URLs work perfectly fine, easy to verify by just putting them as the src of a normal `img` element - https://jsfiddle.net/px0Lrh8o/ That the `picture` element shows only one of them at any given time - that is how it is _supposed_ to work. If that is not what you wanted to begin with, then you chose the wrong element.

Comment: I managed to solve it, using encode url, for some reason srcset, I was unable to access the image through the normal link, but when changing to encodeURIComponent it worked.

Another thing I had to put the size 1x attribute in the url after the end of it

Comment: my code in js 
<picture>
          <source
            srcSet={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDFRONT}${encodeURIComponent(desktop?.key || '')} 1x`}
            media="(min-width: 768px)"
          />
          <img
            src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDFRONT}${encodeURIComponent(mobile?.key || '')}`}
            alt={banners.name}
            className="w-100"
            loading="lazy"
          />
        </picture>